# Very low usable RAM on windows 10 Machine

Tags: windows-10, laptop, memory, dell-vostro

Few months back I bought this laptop from Dell . The model is Vostro 3581( 4Gb Ram ,Intel Graphics 620, 1TB HDD). From beginning I am facing constant lag while using the PC. It hangs every 5-10 minute. Even thought I use it for minimal purposes (Zoom, Word document , Edge etc) I am facing the issue. I have even turned of animations(of win10) but then also the pc is almost unusable

When I look up the task manager I always find above 80% usage(here is the
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wYLM.png)

*Here is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2hJv.png) of the Processes going on.*

Usable ram is always below 1 GB(all apps closed). This isn't acceptable. I have a similar Windows 7 laptop (of Lenovo) which always have 2.5 GB available in same situation .Please provide a long term solution.
Please note that I don't want to upgrade the RAM

Comment: That is a good thing. Windows uses as much memory as is available. When you see large free memory on say 16 GB it is all wasted. So If you have an SSD then you need 4 GB physical memory. If a hard disk you need 8 GB so the hard disk is cached. A little while after booting the speed will be the same.

Comment: Also if you have a faulty program then post the Task Manager's Detail tab sorted by private working set.

Comment: @user1292580 Your blanket statements are inaccurate and not helpful. Please don’t. Caching is in no way the problem or solution here. The RAM is simply _in use_. There’s only 660 MB of cached data.

Comment: @InfinityLies 4 GB are simply not enough. There is no way this is going to work, sorry. Get more RAM. Windows 10 isn’t Windows 7. Other software evolved, too.

Comment: Cached memory is counted in both cache memory and free memory. Also code in cached memory is also the same memory in the program.

Comment: The "long term solution" that you want is to buy more RAM. 4GB is the minimum for an up to date Win10 machine (which is essentially Windows 11 "lite"). Windows 10 originally [needed 2GB back in 2015](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-system-requirements-6d4e9a79-66bf-7950-467c-795cf0386715) but it has grown and now is closer to the Windows 11 requirements https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/windows-11-specifications

Comment: @user1292580 I have updated the screenshot of the Task manager. Dell.D3.Win is ALWAYS on the top. I am not sure whether to delete it or not..

Comment: Why would you delete a service that’s only using 50 MB? Now if you want to uninstall it because it’s unnecessary that’s an entirely different story

Comment: @Ramhound What about MacAfee? My subscription has ended .. Should I delete it?

Comment: That’s entirely up to you

Comment: @DanielB *4 GB are simply not enough* is also a blanket statement. I admit that 4 GB for a *recent* laptop isn't a lot, but my 10 year old pc with 4GB and up to date Windows 10 still runs smoothly. It all depends on what the intended purpose is. Office, browser and e-mail should work without any problem. That said, the question does not give enough information about what could be the problem. Maybe there's some scheduled task kicking in every 5–10 minutes. Personally I'd first use Autoruns to disable all non-essential software, and see if that fixes anything. Find a lightweight AV (not McAfee)

Comment: Dell.D3.Win (Dell Digital Delivery Service) appears to be used to keep the bloatware that comes with a pre-installed PC up-to-date. It should be safe to disable or uninstall it.

Comment: @Berend Deleted it.. Thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4 GB RAM just isn't enough these days, especially in your case.
You said you don't want to hear this, but it is still the answer I'm going to give.

The original requirement for Windows 10, back in 2015 was 2GB, but that was the absolute lower limit and wasn't pleasant to use even then.
Windows 10 has seen 12 new versions since then and has grown a bit more obese.
Most new computers come with 8 GB as standard these days and Windows 10 (and other software) have more or less come to expect that.

These days, if you have a SSD harddisk and a discrete video-card, 4 GB is considered to be really minimal.
And you need more (at least 6 GB) if you have a classic harddisk and/or chipset graphics. You have BOTH in your system.

Furthermore: Zoom and Word are NOT minimal applications. I consider both medium. Edge, when multiple tabs open and depending on the content of the displayed web-pages, can also be far more heavy than you would expect.

So I would really recommend a RAM upgrade AND replace the classic harddisk with a SSD as well. You performance will benefit from either upgrade, but if you can only do 1 upgrade the SSD would most likely give the best boost for you money.

P.S.
From the comments I see that you don't have a McAfee license anymore but you still run it. The screenshot also indicates that is using a fair amount of RAM and disk-IO (the disk-IO is a worse problem than the RAM usage in your case).
I would definitely uninstall it completely. Windows Defender is actually not bad at all as a virus-scanner and it is running anyway in Windows 10. You might as well use it and forget about whatever (little) benefit you still get (without a license) from McAfee.

Comment: @InfinityLies I seriously doubt it. Most anti-virus programs fall back to the level of their "free" product (if they have one, McAfee doesn't). Some others just keep working "as is" without any updates (so still recognize old viruses, but will not recognize newer ones). And others stop working altogether.

Comment: You mentioned that "the disk-IO is a worse problem than the RAM usage " Is it a serious issue? It always remains around 98-100%